# Add total row for each subgroup in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by, sum, row

I have a dataframe , df :

```
BRAND ART_TYPE  YEAR_MONTH metrics  Value
aaa      xyz      201510       a   4500
aaa      xyz      201510       b   8500
bbc      abc      201510       c   3500
bbc      abc      201510       d  10000
xxx      def      201510       e  15000
```

I want to add a total row  for every group of (['BRAND','ART_TYPE','YEAR_MONTH'])
So the result should be :

```
BRAND   ART_TYPE    YEAR_MONTH  metrics Value
aaa     xyz         201510      a       4500
aaa     xyz         201510      b       8500
aaa     xyz         201510      tot     13000
bbc     abc         201510      c       3500
bbc     abc         201510      d       10000
bbc     abc         201510      tot     13500
xxx     def         201510      e       15000
xxx     def         201510      tot     15000
```

How to do this ? Do we have any function? I tried with apply and groupby function , did not work. Please let me know if more information is required for this.

Code I tried adds a column :

```
df['total'] = df.groupby(['BRAND','ART_TYPE','YEAR_MONTH']).apply(calctot)

def calctot(df):
   return(sum(df['Value']))
```

This gave an error , even if it works this will add a column.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change input dataframe according recommended output.
I improved function `calctot` - delete columns and then append sum row. 
Column `level_3` was created from old index, I delete it. New values in column `metrics` after applying function `groupby` was `NaN`, so I fill them by value `tot`.

```
#  BRAND ART_TYPE  YEAR_MONTH metrics  Value
#0   aaa      xyz      201510       a   4500
#1   aaa      xyz      201510       b   8500
#2   bbc      abc      201510       c   3500
#3   bbc      abc      201510       d  10000
#4   xxx      def      201510       e  15000


def calctot(df):
    #delete columns
    df = df.drop(['BRAND', 'ART_TYPE', 'YEAR_MONTH'], axis=1)
    #append sum row, ignoring non-numeric column metrics
    return df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)

#groupby and reset index
df =  df.groupby(['BRAND','ART_TYPE','YEAR_MONTH']).apply(calctot).reset_index()
#delete old index column
df = df.drop(['level_3'], axis=1)
#fill NaN to value tot
df['metrics'] = df['metrics'].fillna('tot')

print df
#  BRAND ART_TYPE  YEAR_MONTH metrics  Value
#0   aaa      xyz      201510       a   4500
#1   aaa      xyz      201510       b   8500
#2   aaa      xyz      201510     tot  13000
#3   bbc      abc      201510       c   3500
#4   bbc      abc      201510       d  10000
#5   bbc      abc      201510     tot  13500
#6   xxx      def      201510       e  15000
#7   xxx      def      201510     tot  15000
```